# Отправка писем с сохранением в отправленных на сервере

Tags: алгоритм, smtp, imap

Хочу, чтобы письмо, отправленное из приложения, можно было найти в папке "отправленные" (mail.ru, например). `SMTP` отправляет, но не сохраняет в папку "отправленные". Через `IMAP` можно в папку поместить письмо, но как отправить? Подскажите правильный алгоритм.

Comment: Делаете 2 раза. Через smpt отправляете, через imap кладете в "отправленные".

Comment: IMAP имеет смысл использовать, когда письмо уже находится на сервере, иначе нужно будет его туда отправлять второй раз, а это уже плохое решение

Comment: Вообще-то smtp и imap сервера могут быть и разными. 

Если честно, про отправку письма IMAP-ом впервые от Вас слышу.

Comment: Да я не говорил про "отправку", я говорил про то, что можно закинуть письмо в папку на сервере, отправляться оно не будет. Outlook как-то сохраняет копию отправленного письма в папке на сервере, которую ему можно указать. Не ясно только одно - неужели письмо штелся два раза) 1) По SMTP 2) по IMAP. Видимо, трафик придется смотреть

Comment: Подозреваю, что outlook (по крайней мере "общаясь" с exchange server) вообще использует MAPI

Comment: Я говорю только про mail.ru. Потому что gmail.com автоматически создает копию отправленных по SMTP писем в папке "отправленные".